# Can Sharepoint Forms be accessed as files?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm working with Lists in Sharepoint 2010. I have a few Forms I've worked on a little ("DispForm.aspx" etc) and was wondering whether the forms are available as files on the server?

If I was working with an aspx file in Visual Studio I could open it up in Notepad... but I can't find my aspx files on the Sharepoint server. Are they not accessible in that way?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that, but the files are stored in the data base and not in the file system, if I remember right. Try to use the Sharepoint Designer, as it lets you connect to the sharepoint site. There you can view all site content, even the forms etc. Make sure that you download the version of sharepoint designer fitting to your office installtion (if you have 32 bit office, you need 32 bit sharepoint designer). A possible place to look for the files in filesystem would be the 14 hive directory: http://sharepointfever.blogspot.ch/2012/07/sharepoint-2010-14-hive-directory.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. 
I was using Sharepoint Designer, but that's failed monumentally (silently failing to open the specified file which still works within Sharepoint) and so I'm looking for work-around options.

Comment: Have you tried opening it in advanced mode? you have to right click on the file and then click on "Edit in Advanced Mode" (who would have thought that XD). I think normally the designer opens aspx files in designer mode. This can be helpful for non programmers / developers, but for me it always screws up the files. Maybe the designer had a problem with your files.

Comment: Ironically right-clicking on the file (well, any file from this site) brings up just a small unlabelled menu box that can't be clicked. 
I've tried to access it from Sharepoint designer on two different PCs with the same result... Fun times :)

Comment: That's why I hate sharepoint ;) Have you installed office on those computers? If so, I wouldn't know anything else to try out. Though it's strange, that the designer acts that weird. For me its sometimes sluggish, but it works...